# How can I place many spans in divs without making code too large?

Tags: html, css

So I have 20 spans with movie genres, and also another 20 spans which "close" the genre once it's chosen and it has an `.active` class, like here:
[image]

And my version looks like this:
[image]

So I add "close" span inside of another span with genre name, and this span gets bigger in size. So I was wondering if there's a way to make it work like in the picture without writing too much code.
HTML code:

```
<div class="genres">
            <span>action<span class="close active">x</span></span>
            <span>adventure</span>
            <span>animation</span>
            <span>comedy</span>
            <span>crime</span>
            <span>documentary</span>
            <span>drama</span>
            <span>family</span>
            <span>fantasy</span>
            <span>history</span>
            <span>horror</span>
            <span>music</span>
            <span>mystery</span>
            <span>romance</span>
            <span>science fiction</span>
            <span>TV movie</span>
            <span>thriller</span>
            <span>war</span>
            <span>western</span>
        </div>
```

So I wanted to add "close" span to every span with genre name, but then it would get too big, and adding these two spans into another div, which would add 20 more divs, would make code too big too.
CSS styles:

```
.genres span{        //style for all spans
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
    display: flex;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
    line-height: 3px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding:10px;
    font-size: 0.850rem;
    margin:2px;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.genres span.close{        //style for "close" spans
    display: inline;
    text-transform: none;
    padding: 10px;
    margin:0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    color: #3f51b5;
    background-color: rgba(172, 157, 157, 0.7);;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried rendering it with Javascript? Put the text of the spans into a list, then render it. Do you understand? I can give you an example if you want.

Comment: @LublubXT hi! i have something in my mind but can't understand fully, could you provide an example?

Comment: Ok I already made it!

Comment: Waite where you wanting the `x` button to hide the span? Did I misunderstand?

Comment: @LublubXT sorry, i don't understand your question
i want the close span to be hidden when it's not active, but it should show up when it's active, i just don't know how to do it in html

Comment: Oh ok, like a drop down, where you press the button it shows the span, then when not active it hides it. Ok no problem, just give me a sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help you further.

```js
const genresElement = document.querySelector('.genres');
const genres = ['action', 'adventure','animation', 'comedy','crime','documentary', 'drama','family','fantasy','history','horror','music','mystery','romance','science fiction','TV movie','thriller','war','western'];
let selectedGenres = [];
let htmlToAdd = '';

genres.forEach(genre => htmlToAdd += `<span>${genre}</span>`);
genresElement.innerHTML = htmlToAdd;

genresElement.addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
  let el = e.target;
  if(el.tagName === 'SPAN')
    el.classList.contains('active') ? addRemoveGenre(el,'remove',el.textContent) : addRemoveGenre(el,'add',el.textContent);
});

function addRemoveGenre(el,action,genre){
  el.classList[action]('active');
  action === 'add' ? selectedGenres.push(genre) : selectedGenres.splice(selectedGenres.indexOf(genre), 1);
  console.log('selected genres: '+selectedGenres);
}
```

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
.genres {
  background: #39445a;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 1em;
}

.genres > span {
  color: #444;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #e0e0e0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.genres > span.active {
  background: #4050b5;
  color: #fff;
}

.active::after {
  content: 'x';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 12px;
  font-size: 6px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<h2>Click the genres below.<br></h2>
<div class="genres"></div>
```

Comment: Rendering each element one at a time can create a performance issue, so I would instead add each "element" to a string and _then_ add all of them to `genresElement.innerHTML`. Still upvoted though. :)

Comment: @RickardElimää, okay., so as ```htmlToAdd``` in the updated example?

Comment: Yeah, perfect. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add close button to all .active spans then add the close button using ::after from css only, no need to do anything in html.

[Working example here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-w7vsfg?file=styles.css)

Html

```
<div class="genres">
      <span class="active">action</span>
      <span class="active">adventure</span>
      <span>animation</span>
      <span>comedy</span>
      <span>crime</span>
      <span>documentary</span>
      <span>drama</span>
      <span>family</span>
      <span>fantasy</span>
      <span>history</span>
      <span>horror</span>
      <span>music</span>
      <span>mystery</span>
      <span>romance</span>
      <span>science fiction</span>
      <span>TV movie</span>
      <span>thriller</span>
      <span>war</span>
      <span>western</span>
    </div>
```

Updated CSS -

```
body {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 53);
}

.genres span {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(182, 182, 182);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  margin: 2px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.genres span.active {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.genres span.active::after {
  content: 'X';
  padding: 0 6px;
  background-color: rgb(212, 212, 212);
  color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: hi! css only seems like a good idea, but i'm not sure i can use these elements in javascript code, for example: when span with text is active, i need to click on a close button so it stops being active and close button hides

Comment: I can't work out how you would attach an event listener to a pseufo element.

Answer (score 1):

To align items inside flex you will need to use `align-items: center;` in parent cells:

```
.genres span{
    align-items: center; //this is the key
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
    display: flex;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
    line-height: 3px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding:10px;
    font-size: 0.850rem;
    margin:2px;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```html
<style>
    .genres span {
        /* */
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
        display: flex;
        text-transform: capitalize;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: #fff;
        line-height: 3px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 0.850rem;
        margin: 2px;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .genres span.close {
        display: inline;
        text-transform: none;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0;
        border-radius: 10px;
        font-size: 0.8rem;
        color: #3f51b5;
        background-color: rgba(172, 157, 157, 0.7);
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="genres" id="main">
        <span>action<span class="close active">x</span></span>

    </div>

    <script>
        var tag = document.createElement("p");

        const text = ['Text1', 'Text2', 'Text3'];

        for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            var txt = document.createTextNode(text[i]);
            tag.appendChild(txt);
            var br = document.createElement("br");
            tag.appendChild(txt);
            tag.appendChild(br);
            var element = document.getElementsByClassName("genres")[0];
            element.appendChild(tag);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

It renders it with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

your code should look like below. you can add further styling yourself.

```
<div class="genres">
            <span>action<span class="close ">x</span></span>
            <span>adventure<span class="close ">x</span></span>
            <span>animation<span class="close ">x</span></span>
            <span>comedy</span>
            <span>crime</span>
            <span>documentary</span>
            <span>drama</span>
            <span>family</span>
            <span>fantasy</span>
            <span>history</span>
            <span>horror</span>
            <span>music</span>
            <span>mystery</span>
            <span>romance</span>
            <span>science fiction</span>
            <span>TV movie</span>
            <span>thriller</span>
            <span>war</span>
            <span>western</span>
        </div>
```

**css should look like below**

```
 .genres span {
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
        text-transform: capitalize;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: rgba(52, 62, 199, 0.87);
        display: inline;
        font-size: 9px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    span.close {
        background: white;
display: inline-block;
line-height: 1.2;
padding: 0;
margin: 0px;
width: 12px;
height: 12px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: 900;
text-transform: lowercase;
margin-left: 5px;
    }
```